# htaccess mod_rewrite rules for IIS with QSA flag

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, iis-8.5

IIS Version 8.5 for Windows Server 2012 R2 Version 6.2

This .htaccess rule which is working on my local dev which is wamp

```
RewriteRule ^.*search/?(.*)$ /displayPage.php?page=search&%1 [QSA]
```

I am importing this into an IIS server and it is rewritten as:

```
Rewrite ^.*search/?(.*)$ /displayPage.php?page=search&{C:1}
```

Now when I submit my search the url displayed is:

> http://example.com/search?keyword=sample+text&cat=1

The page loads a `500 error`. When I disable the rule I get a `404 error`.

When editing the rule, the Append query string is checked.

So I added a var_dump and echo with an exit just to verify if it reaches the `displayPage.php`. It did not.

So the rule that was imported does not seem to be configured correctly. How can I fix it?

**SOLUTION:**

1. Open the edit rule window in IIS
2. select the test pattern button
3. In Test pattern window in field Input data to text: search/?keyword=test+sample&cat=123
4. The result displayed R:1 = ?keyword=test+sample&cat=123
5. So Modify the rule from {C:1} to {R:1}
6. Refresh page and the magic continues!!!

   The Rewrite URL is now as follows: `/displayPage.php?page=search&{R:1}`

Comment: Why don't you use apples to apples. It makes more sense from a consistency standpoint to use the same platform. If you're going to develop on an Apache server you should use an Apache server on the real server. Doesn't make sense to go Apache to IIS.  Use IIS or Apache and save yourself random issues. IMO.

Comment: @PanamaJack That doesn't answer the question. I understand what you're saying but I'm working in environment where this is what was there before I arrived so I am making best do with the resources that have been provided.